# Updating previous year values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table T like this:

```
ID|DESC1_ID | DESC2_ID | TS     | CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR| CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR|ID2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------|-
1 |1        |1         |31.01.22|                    | 220                |1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 |1        |2         |31.01.22|                    | 500                |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 |1        |3         |31.01.22|                    | 22                 |1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 |2        |1         |31.01.22|                    | 50                 |1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 |1        |1         |01.02.23|                    | 230                |2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
6 |1        |2         |01.02.23|                    | 300                |2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
7 |1        |3         |01.02.23|                    | 32                 |2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
8 |2        |1         |01.02.23|                    | 30                 |2
```

I wish to update the field CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR for all entries where id2 is 2.
The value should be a previous year value. It could happen, that the date(TS) is not exactly from 1 year before.
I have a query below which does what I want.

```
UPDATE T t1  
    SET CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR = (SELECT NVL(CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR , 0)
                                FROM T t2
                              WHERE t2.TS = (SELECT MAX(TS) 
                                             FROM T
                                             WHERE TS BETWEEN  ADD_MONTHS( t1.TS - 7, -12) AND ADD_MONTHS( t1.TS, -12)
                                             AND DESC1_ID = t1.DESC1_ID
                                             AND DESC2_ID = t1.DESC2_ID )
                            AND t2.DESC1_ID = t.DESC1_ID
                            AND t2.DESC2_ID = t.DESC2_ID )  
WHERE ID2 = 2 ;
```

I wanted to ask if there is a better way to reach the goal.

**UPDATE:**

As everything is simplified it happened only by the coincidence that ID2 for previous year is 1 and for this year is 2. In the reality there are much more values.

**UPDATE:**
The values are stored daily(on working days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
works on **daily** bases even if some dates don't exist in previous year. In that case the first date before that is fetched.

```sql
UPDATE A_TBL t
SET t.CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR = (  Select PREV_CUM  
                               From ( SELECT      t.DESC1_ID, t.DESC2_ID, MAX(t.TS) "TS", MAX(t.CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR) "PREV_CUM"
                                      FROM        A_TBL t
                                      INNER JOIN  A_TBL t2 ON(t2.DESC1_ID = t.DESC1_ID And t2.DESC2_ID = t.DESC2_ID)
                                      WHERE       To_Number(To_Char(t.TS, 'yyyymmdd')) <= To_Number(To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(t2.TS, -12), 'yyyymmdd'))
                                      GROUP BY    t.DESC1_ID, t.DESC2_ID 
                                    )
                              Where DESC1_ID = t.DESC1_ID And DESC2_ID = t.DESC2_ID  )
WHERE t.ID2 = 2;
```

All that you need is the innermost query which gives you the data from the same date or first one before in previous year of that in row with ID2 = 2 (one beeing updated). This is the query:

```sql
SELECT      t.DESC1_ID, t.DESC2_ID, MAX(t.TS) "TS", MAX(t.CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR) "PREV_CUM"
FROM        A_TBL t
INNER JOIN  A_TBL t2 ON(t2.DESC1_ID = t.DESC1_ID And t2.DESC2_ID = t.DESC2_ID)
WHERE       To_Number(To_Char(t.TS, 'yyyymmdd')) <= To_Number(To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(t2.TS, -12), 'yyyymmdd'))
GROUP BY    t.DESC1_ID, t.DESC2_ID 

  DESC1_ID   DESC2_ID TS          PREV_CUM
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
         2          1 31-JAN-22         50 
         1          2 31-JAN-22        500 
         1          3 31-JAN-22         22 
         1          1 31-JAN-22        220
```

The result after the update is:

```sql
Select * From A_TBL;
```

| ID | DESC1_ID | DESC2_ID | TS | CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR | CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 31-JAN-22 |  | 220 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 31-JAN-22 |  | 500 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 31-JAN-22 |  | 22 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 31-JAN-22 |  | 50 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 01-FEB-23 | 220 | 230 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 01-FEB-23 | 500 | 300 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | 01-FEB-23 | 22 | 32 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 | 1 | 01-FEB-23 | 50 | 30 | 2 |

Comment: Thank you. However the values are stored for every day. So it is not enough to get the year only. I made an update.

Comment: @hajduk Just posted an updated answer that covers daily values from year before regardless the existance of the exact same date. Hopefuly, it could help you. "Hajduk živi vječno"...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, I think you are looking for this:

```
UPDATE table_name A
SET CUM_MONTH_PREV_YEAR = (SELECT B.CUM_MONTH_THIS_YEAR
                           FROM table_name B
                           WHERE A.id2 - 1 = B.id2
                             AND A.DESC1_ID = B.DESC1_ID
                             AND A.DESC2_ID = B.DESC2_ID);
                             
 SELECT *
 FROM table_name;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. AÍ have made an update. It is not a rule, that ID2 is 1 and 2.